# "WITH CHECK OPTION" and "TOP" causes error when upgrading to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

Whilst looking to upgrade a Microsoft SQL Server from 2014 to 2016, I ran Microsoft's Data Migration Assistant, and a breaking change was found with the `WITH CHECK OPTION` when using a view in a table.

Whilst looking through Microsoft's various pages for help, it seemed that they were dead-ends. Our current compatibility version is 120, and one option to fix was downgrading it to 90; however this isn't possible.

[image]

The code breaking is:

```
CREATE VIEW [table]
AS  
    SELECT TOP 1000000
        [Id],
        [UserName],
        [Firstname]
    FROM 
        [Users] WITH (NOLOCK)
    WITH CHECK OPTION 
GO
```

Does anyone have a fix for this? Otherwise it seems upgrading to 2016 version will not work.

Comment: Why does that view need that option?

Comment: @artm I took fields out, privacy concern, if that's what you're confused about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, if you follow the `MSDN` official documentation [Create View (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)  you will note the following in the *UPDATABLE VIEWS* section:

> You can modify the data of an underlying base table through a view, as long as the following conditions are true:
>
> ...
>
> `TOP` is not used anywhere in the select_statement of the view together with the `WITH CHECK OPTION` clause.

So it is highly possible that the `SQL Server` team have enforced this impossibility as the CHECK

> Forces data modification statements executed against the view to follow the criteria set within select_statement.

Obviously, you will not be able to normally edit the code with the combined, so perhaps the answer is clear.